# Multi level accepts_nested_attributes_for | Strong Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create multi-level object on one go. But getting error in Strong Parameter.

**Error**

```
Unpermitted parameter: abc
```

**Rails 4**

```
def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).permit(
    :event_id, 
    :description,
    child_attributes: [
      :people_count,
      :some_attribute,
      :some_other_attribute,
      grandchild_attributes: [:abc]
    ]
  )
end
```

PS: Using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in both models. But that is of no concern in Strong params I think anyway.

Comment: what are your assosciations?

Comment: **Parent** `has_one` **Child**.... **Child** `has_one` **Grandchild** ... And the **Grandchild** has that `:abc` attribute.